# 3d array Matlab plot

Tags: arrays, matlab, 3d, plot, histogram

I'm a little stuck plotting a 3D array in MATLAB. I have created some histograms that vary as I change a certain threshold. Meaning, for t=65, I have one histogram, for t=70, another and so on. I would like to make a 3D plot or surface where the third dimension is this threshold (t from 0-100 intervals of 5) and the other two dimensions are intensity and frequency respectively (as for the 2D histogram). How can I do that? I've looked at most of the plotting tools such as surf, isosurface, slices and so on. None of them seem to do the trick. My matrix is 80x100x20 where the 20 dimension is that of the threshold. Any ideas? THANKS!

Comment: Is your matrix 80x100x20 _after_ you histogram it? Otherwise, what is the extra dimension?

Comment: @elektrochose: a regular histogram produce 1D data (for each bin, you have a count/frequency). Can you be more specific regarding your data matrix?

Comment: My mistake, matrix is 2x80x20.
There is 80 bins. 
And 20 histograms.

Comment: Matrix really should have been 80x20

Comment: @elektrochose: This is often a point of confusion: you are plotting a 3D bar graph, but the underlying data is really 2D

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an example might help:

```
%# 20 intervals
t = linspace(0,100,20+1);
labels = strtrim(cellstr(num2str([t(1:end-1);t(2:end)]', '[%g,%g)\n')));  %#'

%# some sample data parametrized by t
x = randn(1000,20);
[count,bins] = hist(x, 10);

%# plot 3D bar graph
bar3(bins, count, 'histc')

xlabel('param intervals'), ylabel('bins'), zlabel('counts')
set(gca, 'XTick',1:2:20, 'XTickLabel',labels(1:2:end))
axis tight
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yes! This is what I was looking for. I realize my mistake now. I thought I was dealing with 3 dimensions when really I only had 2. Your example helped me tons! Thank you